# Why do I get a trait not implemented for an optional field in Diesel struct

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have this struct:

```
#[table_name = "clients"]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, Insertable, Identifiable, Associations)]
pub struct Client {
    pub id: Option<i64>,
    pub name: String,
    pub rank: Option<i64>,
}
```

and the following implementation:

```
impl Client {
    pub fn get(name: String, connection: &PgConnection) -> Option<Self> {
        match clients::table
            .filter(clients::name.eq(&name))
            .limit(1)
            .load::<Client>(connection)
        {
            Ok(clients) => Some(clients[0]),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

which gives me the following error:

```
.load::<Client>(connection) {                                                                                   
 ^^^^ the trait `diesel::Queryable<diesel::sql_types::BigInt, _>` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<i64>`
```

Comment: Note that if you want to return an owned client and not a reference, instead of your match, you could write `.ok().and_then(|clients| clients.into_iter().next())`.

Comment: What did you put in your `table` macro? I guess that the issue is there.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what the schema is, for example. Try to reproduce your error in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) and [Diesel-specific tips](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust-diesel/info) as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error message says that you cannot query a `BigInt` (a 64 bits int) into an `Option<i64>`. That is because you forgot to say that `id` is nullable in your [table declaration](https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/macro.table.html). It must look like:

```
table! {
    clients {
        id -> Nullable<BigInt>,
        name -> Text,
        rank -> Nullable<BigInt>,
    }
}
```

You can see the implementation of `Queryable` you are looking for [in the documentation](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html#impl-Queryable%3CNullable%3CST%3E%2C%20DB%3E).

Comment: I got this error because I was re-using the same struct for inserting and selecting. This is a pattern where the `DEFAULT` fields (i.e. `id SERIAL`) are defined as `Option<i64>`, but the schema is generated based on the migrations and the field in the database is not optional. I have to modify the schema manually after each migration (which is fine I think).

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was not realising that diesel maps fields based **entirely on the order of fields** in the struct. **It completely ignores field names**.

If your struct has fields defined in a different order to the `schema.rs` file then it will map them incorrectly and cause type errors.

https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html#deriving

> When this trait is derived, it will assume that the order of fields on your struct match the order of the fields in the query. This means that field order is significant if you are using `#[derive(Queryable)]`. Field name has no effect.

Comment: See [Why does order of fields in struct need to match table! in Diesel?](/q/77169378/2189130).